# unable to execute server.js program using express framework on node.js

Tags: node.js, express

While trying to execute server.js program I am getting the following error:

```
var app = express();
Type error: object is not a function 
   at object.<anonymous>
```

even tried re installing and changing the version of express to

```
npm install
npm uninstall express
npm install express@2.5.9
```

but it resulted in new `error`

```
fqdn = ~req.url.indexof(' ://')
```

I use windows and i am working on node.js version 0.8.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Express < 3.0, the return value of `require('express');` is not a function; you'll need to create a server the old way.

**Express 2.x**

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express.createServer();
```

**Express 3.x**

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
> require('express').version;
'3.0.0rc2'
```

return?

As you can see it does return `3.0.0rc2`? Does yours really return `2.5.9`. if it does you use like Brandon said 2.x section. If it returns 3.x you use his 3.x section.

Comment: **require is not recognized as an internal or external command**
says the reply. and since i have passed **npm install express@2.5.9** so version 2.5.9 must have got installed only.

Comment: Alfred was intending you to do that from within node's REPL, not directly from the command line.

Comment: Yup from within the REPL, because it might be possible you think you have some version while in fact you have another version...